# C++ using std::accumulate to generate a map<int,int>

Tags: c++, dictionary, vector, lambda, accumulate

I have a problem creating a `std::map<int, int>` from a vector of pointers, called `files`. Each pointer points to an object with three member variables, one of which is `size` of type `int`. The key of the map would be the `size` and the value would be the number of objects which have the same `size`.

Do NOT waste your time on the second one! It is the next step in my program and I have figured it out already, I think. For initialization of the map I am using `std::accumulate`, because it returns a value. I am using `std::tr1::shared_ptr` for the pointers and a lambda expression for the predicate function. I am having problems with compilation.

Here's the code snippet:

```
map<int,int>* sizes = new map<int,int>();
sizes = accumulate(files.begin(), files.end(),sizes,
[&sizes](map<int,int> acc, shared_ptr<CFileType>& obj)
{
    return sizes->insert(pair<int,int>(obj->getSize(),0));
});
```

Here's the error:

> error C2664: 'std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2> `anonymous-namespace'::::operator ()(std::map<_Kty,_Ty>,std::tr1::shared_ptr &) const' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'std::map<_Kty,_Ty> ' to 'std::map<_Kty,_Ty>'

I am not very sure what to pass to the lambda function. I have tried with `pair<int, int>`, but it didn't work. Also, I must mention that this map is returned to another function, so it has to be a pointer.

Any help from you would be appreciated. Thanks!

---

**UPDATE:**

Problem solved, here is the solution:

```
map<int,int>* sizes = accumulate(files.begin(), files.end(), new map<int,int>(),
    [](map<int,int>* acc, shared_ptr<CFileType>& obj)->map<int,int>*
    {
        acc->insert(pair<int,int>(obj->getSize(),0));
        return acc;
    });
```

Comment: Why are you new’ing your map? This isn’t Java...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message is that you have a type mismatch between the two kinds of `std::map`s.  It looks like the error is in the code that **calls** the lambda, which apparently passes the wrong thing for the `acc` parameter.  The good news is that the lambda, as posted, never actually uses the `acc` parameter.

Comment: Which are the two kinds of "map" that I have? And thanks for finding an unneeded algorithm, i do want to use "acc", but have used "sizes" in the lambda function.

Comment: Although I know the type of one of the `map`s, I don't see the type of the other.  But the error message "`cannot convert parameter 1 from 'std::map<_Kty,_Ty> ' to 'std::map<_Kty,_Ty>'`" means exactly that, even though it doesn't tell you the types of `_Kty` and `_Ty` in each of the maps.  You'll have to see what you're passing as the first parameter to the lambda when you actually use the lambda, and determine how the type differs from `std::map<int, int>`.

Comment: It works now, I didn`t realize map.insert() does not return the map, but the pair it inserts. the code works now.